# Starting MediaPlayer - Hits error in stmt mp.Start() - Null Exception Erro

Tags: android

Please suggest me, how to rectify this error,

It is because of Android Build Target, it set as 4.2.2

**Logcat**

```
05-01 02:31:01.081: E/AndroidRuntime(1124): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-01 02:31:01.081: E/AndroidRuntime(1124):     at com.vpl.ramrevhashu.medicaplayerfunmeth.Splash.onCreate(Splash.java:19)
05-01 02:31:01.081: E/AndroidRuntime(1124):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
05-01 02:31:01.081: E/AndroidRuntime(1124):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
05-01 02:31:01.081: E/AndroidRuntime(1124):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
05-01 02:31:01.081: E/AndroidRuntime(1124):     ... 11 more
05-01 02:31:08.240: I/Process(1124): Sending signal. PID: 1124 SIG: 9<
```

**Code**

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.MediaPlayer; 
import android.os.Bundle;



public class Splash extends Activity{

    MediaPlayer ourSound;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle SplashPage) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(SplashPage);
        setContentView(R.layout.splash);
        ourSound = new MediaPlayer();
        ourSound = MediaPlayer.create(Splash.this, R.raw.song);
        ourSound.start(); //(Error at this stmt)

        Thread timer = new Thread(){

            public void run(){
                try{
                    sleep(5000);
                } catch(InterruptedException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } finally{
                    Intent startPage = new Intent("com.vpl.ramrevhashu.medicaplayerfunmeth");
                    startActivity(startPage);
                }
            }
        };
        timer.start();

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        super.onPause();
        ourSound.release();
        finish();
    }


}
```

Comment: `ourSound` is null cause this `ourSound = MediaPlayer.create(Splash.this, R.raw.song)` fails. Also you don't need `ourSound = new MediaPlayer();`

Answer (score 0):

Try this ... it works

```
static Boolean audioPlay = false;
static MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();

// Audio play Function
public static void playAudio(int val) 
{
    if (MainActivity.audioPlay) 
    {
        if (!MainActivity.mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) 
        {
            MainActivity.mediaPlayer.reset();
            MainActivity.mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, val);

            try 
            {
                MainActivity.mediaPlayer.start();
                MainActivity.mediaPlayer.setLooping(false);
            } 
            catch (IllegalStateException e) 
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        MainActivity.audioPlay = true;
    }
}
```

For calling or playing the music file named 'song' from 'raw' folder, call the function like this....

```
playAudio(R.raw.song);
```